# RFC822 Message-Id in new Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api, google-schemas

We are trying to set manually the RFC822 Message-Id when sending emails using the gmail api.
We have tested but seen that Gmail overrides our value.
Do you know if there is a reason for this? Can we do something for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the Message-Id is always set for mail sending to be the proper format for outgoing Gmail mail, the same format as the web interface.

What exactly is reason for needing to specify your own value instead of using either the message.id value returned during send for your own identifier or the final Message-Id header?

Comment: changing this would help make sending email idempotent especially when you can search by the RFC 2822 ID through the search endpoint.

Comment: do we get Message-Id in send response too using gmailApi?

Comment: this is mandatory to reply to a mailing list message with a vote mechanism (i.e. Apache Incubator Graduation) when you are not subscribed to a list when the message shows up and you cannot simply reply to :-)

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about specifying a custom Message-Id is that the Id value will be passed thru to replies of the original message via the "References" header which makes it a nice method for tracking an email thread without having an extra lookup database to associate an ID with other data.

I'm looking for some kind of alternative since google does not let you override their value...