# Gmail API is overriding the custom Message-ID header while sending emails

Tags: google-api, gmail, jakarta-mail, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

We are manually setting a custom Message-ID header while sending emails using Java MimeMessage. The Message-ID format is following the RFC822 standard. However, on sending the mail via the Gmail API, the Message-ID header is getting overwritten with a new one from gmail.

Instead if we we Java Mail and send the email via SMTP, the custom Message-ID is retained by Gmail.

Is there a way to have a custom Message-ID while sending email via the Gmail API ?

I have checked the following question, but I am not sure if its still the case. ([RFC822 Message-Id in new Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749488/rfc822-message-id-in-new-gmail-api))

[UPDATE]

EmailMimeMessage.scala

```
package utils.email

import javax.mail._
import javax.mail.internet._

import play.api.Logger

class EmailMimeMessage(session: Session, messageId: String) extends MimeMessage(session) {

  @throws(classOf[MessagingException])
  override def updateMessageID(): Unit = {
    Logger.info(s"[EmailMimeMessage] before sending add message id: $messageId")
    setHeader("Message-ID", messageId)
  }

}
```

GmailApiService.scala

```
package utils.email

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.util.Properties
import javax.mail.Session
import javax.mail.internet.{InternetAddress, MimeMessage}

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.{BearerToken, Credential}
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory
import com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail

import scala.util.Try

case class EmailToBeSent(

  to_email: String,
  from_email: String,
  from_name: String,
  reply_to_email: String,
  subject: String,
  textBody: String,
  htmlBody: String,
  message_id: String    
)


object GmailApiService {

  private val APPLICATION_NAME: String = "Gmail API Java Quickstart"

  private val JSON_FACTORY: JsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance

  private val HTTP_TRANSPORT: HttpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()


  def createEmail(emailToBeSent: EmailToBeSent): Try[MimeMessage] = Try {
    val props = new Properties()
    val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
    val email = new EmailMimeMessage(session, emailToBeSent.message_id)

    email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailToBeSent.from_email))

    email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailToBeSent.to_email))

    email.setSubject(emailToBeSent.subject)

    email.setText(emailToBeSent.textBody)

    email
  }

  def createMessageWithEmail(email: MimeMessage) = Try {

    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
    email.writeTo(baos)

    val encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(baos.toByteArray)
    val message = new com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message()

    message.setRaw(encodedEmail)

    message
  }

  def sendGmailService(emailToBeSent: EmailToBeSent, accessToken: String) = Try {

    val credential = new Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod)
  .setAccessToken(accessToken)

    val service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build

    val user = "me"
    val message = createEmail(emailToBeSent) flatMap { email => createMessageWithEmail(email) }

    val sentMessage = service.users().messages().send(user, message.get).execute()

    sentMessage
  }



}
```

On calling GmailApiService.sendGmailService as follows (with Message-ID: "<1495728783999.123.456.local@examplegmail.com>"), in the sent email the Message-ID is overwritten by GMail with something like "YYfdasCAN=-fdas432HFD43FD_THD@mail.gmail.com":

```
val emailToBeSent = EmailToBeSent(
  to_email = "mary_to@gmail.com",
  from_email = "john_from@examplegmail.com",
  from_name = "John Doe",
  reply_to_email = "john_from@gmail.com",
  subject = "How are you ?",
  textBody = "Hey, how are you ?",
  htmlBody = "<strong>Hey, how are you ?</strong>",
  message_id ="<1495728783999.123.456.local@examplegmail.com>",
  in_reply_to_id = None,
  sender_email_settings_id = 0
)

val sentMsg = GmailApiService.sendGmailService(emailToBeSent, GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN).get
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you, added code that I am using to test sending the emails, along with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer from 2014 is still correct: [RFC822 Message-Id in new Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749488/rfc822-message-id-in-new-gmail-api)

Gmail always sets the RFC822 Message-Id header on outgoing emails.

Comment: But this is not the solution. Please provide the solution, can we set our custom message-Id header while sending emails via gmail api.