# Gmail API is overwriting the custom Message-ID header while sending emails

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

We are using the Gmail API to send emails on behalf of the users of our App.  On the header of the emails we send via the Gmail API, we are setting a custom Message-ID.

Nevertheless Gmail is overwriting the Message-ID we set with a different one . The following are some Message-IDs that we have tried:

<8368110f-6ffc-46f8-8e67-7ebf0e1a1d83@domain>

<4fb7a8b7013099c524f70906e009b46218461fff0b2dc0f8b794eb2df26e93d7@domain>

Any idea why this ID overwriting is happening ?

I would really appreciate any help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749488/rfc822-message-id-in-new-gmail-api

Comment: Thanks @payne there is a similar question, the problem is that there is not any accurate answer. Any idea on how to solve that overwriting of the Message-ID in the headers? ... thanks

Comment: From the research I've done, I don't think it's possible and I believe that Google will always generate/provide/overwrite the Message-Id in the header.  I suspect this is by design because being able to choose the Message ID might allow creative folks to get around certain spam filtering methods.  And I agree, it's not clearly documented by Google (any place I can find).

Comment: Thanks for your comment and the research you have done. I thought the same but I have tested other products that send the Message-ID customized. Im not sure how they do, but as they do it, it is possible to create a custom Message-ID in the header when sending an email.I spoke with the Google Cloud support team, but they always send you to one forum where there is not an accurate response - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.mail.sendmail/gkRdBwka4iw- in the forum people say it's about a the formar. Thanks again for your support @payne if we find the way, I will keep you posted

Comment: @Nayib did you find any way to generate this Message-ID?

Comment: We were using the Gmail SMTP api to set message-ids. This year, Google forced us to move back to their REST API which has less capabilities (you also can't send text/ics attachments) and it no longer works. This is incredibly annoying, and the response does not include the message-id. I guess you have to make a second request for every send just to find out the message-id?

Answer (score 0):

You can try custom id with .(dot) before left side of '@'.
It worked for me.

For more details, Please refer the following RFC's. These are really helpful for creating syntax for Custom message-id.

1. [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.4)
2. [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.4)

Hope this would also work for you.

Comment: Did you use SMTP API to send out email or Rest API? If it's Rest API, which one did you use? Thank you!